# scala lower bound type "with" another type?

Tags: scala

Here is the code

```
class Result[A] {
    def map[B](f: (Result[A] => Result[B]), xResult: Result[A]) = {
      xResult match {
        case Success(x)    => Success(f(xResult))
        case Failure(errs) => Failure(errs)
      }
    }

    def apply[B](fResult: Result[A], xResult: Result[B]) = {
      (fResult, xResult) match {
        case (Success(f), Success(x))        => Success((f, x))
        case (Failure(errs), Success(a))     => Failure(errs)
        case (Success(a), Failure(errs))     => Failure(errs)
        case (Failure(errs), Failure(errs2)) => Failure(List(errs, errs2))
      }
    }
  }

  case class Success[A](a: A) extends Result[A] {}

  case class Failure[A](a: A) extends Result[A] {}

  def createCustomerId(id: Int) = {
    if (id > 0)
      Success(id)
    else
      Failure("CustomerId must be positive")
  }
```

Here are the questions

1) result from type inference from method createCustomer is like this

```
Product with Serializable with Result[_ >: Int with String]
```

I dont have trouble with the "Product with Serializable" stuff, the thing im wondering is how to do something meaningfull with the result, and just out of curiosity how to initialize a type like that.

suppose i have another method as shown below

```
def createCustomer(customerId: Result[_ >: Int with String], email: Result[String]) = {
    how can i read/do something with "customerId" argument
  }
```

how to initialize a type like that

```
val x: Result[Int with String] = ???
```

notes:

1. i know my Result class doesnt have any generic "getter"
2. I know that perhaps things could be easier in method "createCustomerId" if when id > 0 i returned Success(id.ToString), but i really want to know whats going on with this lower type and how i could take advantage (if possible) in the future

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your type definition states that both `Success` and `Failure` take the same argument type. However, you actually want to put some other type of argument into `Failure` while still keeping covariance. Here is the simplest fix:

```
class Result[A] {

  def map[B](f: (Result[A] => Result[B]), xResult: Result[A]) = {
    xResult match {
      case Success(x) => Success(f(xResult))
      case Failure(errs) => Failure(errs)
    }
  }

  def apply[B](fResult: Result[A], xResult: Result[B]) = {
    (fResult, xResult) match {
      case (Success(f), Success(x)) => Success((f, x))
      case (Failure(errs), Success(a)) => Failure(errs)
      case (Success(a), Failure(errs)) => Failure(errs)
      case (Failure(errs), Failure(errs2)) => Failure(List(errs, errs2))
    }
  }
}

case class Success[A](a: A) extends Result[A] {}

case class Failure[A, B](a: B) extends Result[A] {}

object TestResult extends App {

  def createCustomerId(id: Int): Result[Int] = {
    if (id > 0)
      Success(id)
    else
      Failure("CustomerId must be positive")
  }

  println(createCustomerId(0))
  println(createCustomerId(1))
}
```

prints:

```
Failure(CustomerId must be positive)
Success(1)
```

If you don't annotate return type for `createCustomerId` with `Result[Int]` compiler will infer `Result[_ <: Int] with Product with Serializable` which is probably not ideal but not too bad.